# Django migration non existent parent node after moving to production server

Tags: django, django-migrations, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my app on PythonAnywhere and when i go to apply the migrations i get an error that a migration dependency does not exist.

I've completely reset the migrations by deleting them from the migrations folder, dropping the database and re-creating it, and running makemigrations.

I only have my one initial migration now and everything works on my local machine.

workflow goes like this:

1 - clone the current version I'm using to PythonAnywhere.
2 - run ./manage migrate to initialize the database (the very first time) and get error:

```
(rwe) 17:00 ~/rwe (develop)$ ./manage.py migrate
asyncio      DEBUG    Using selector: EpollSelector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 86, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/IAMCB/.virtualenvs/rwe-Cn2YEGYr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration backend.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0013_delete_users')
(rwe) 17:12 ~/rwe (develop)$
```

The website loads, and I can browse, etc.. I just can't use anything that relies on the database considering the initial migration hasn't been applied.

The only real change between the systems is the secret key is different for production and DEBUG=False

Comment: Your migrations apparently have some missing files. Perhaps the `auth/migrations/0013_delete_users.py` is not added to the repository.

Comment: as for as i can tell 'auth' refers to django.contrib.auth which is in my settings file and I only have 2 apps neither of which are 'auth'

Comment: Yes, `auth` refers to `django.contrib.auth` and it is an application in your django project, only it's not "yours" as it is part of django itself. You still need migrations generated for it.

Comment: OK your correct, the migrations for django.contrib.auth on my local machine goes to 0013, however the migrations only go to 0011 on the python anywhere dev server?!?    How can i resolve this, are migrations not supposed to be tracked with version control? and running ./manage makemigration causes the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I updated django from 2.2.3 to 3.0.3 and the migrations I am missing must have generated during my use of 2.2.3.

worked for me but not for my PythonAnywhere server. I've recreated my virtualenv on my dev machine and reset all my migrations. Everything is now matching up without issue.